# How to update a TKinter display in a seperate (main) loop?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I have a main loop and would like to monitor the values getting changed in my process in a tkinter display.

I considered something like:

```
from Tkinter import *
import thread
import time


class monitor(Frame):

    def __init__(self):

        self.root=Tk()
        Frame.__init__(self, self.root)
        self.pack()
        self.t = StringVar()
        Label(self.root, textvariable=self.t).pack()

    def start(self):
        #self.mainloop()
        thread.start_new_thread(self.mainloop,(None,))

    def write(self,txt):
        self.t.set(txt)

#Monitoring
m=monitor()    
m.start()

#Main process
for i in range(10):
    m.write("Value is "+str(i))
    time.sleep(1)
```

However I can't set the tkinter object from the outside of thread I started the mainloop. (Unhandled exception in thread started by ...)

How should I solve this the easiest way?

Answer (score 0):

You can't run `mainloop` in a different thread from where you create the widgets. Instead, move your "main process" into a thread.